# How prove this number of the "Fixed subset" is odd

Tags: elementary-set-theory, contest-math

> Let mapping $f:I\to I$ where $I=\{1,2,3,\cdots,n\}$,and **the nonempty set $A\subset I$** such
> $$f(A)=\{b|\exists a\in A,f(a)=b\}$$
> we called “Fixed subset”，if such $f(A)=A$

**Question:**

> show that:
>
> The number of the "Fixed subset" is always odd?

This problem is from Peking University  2014 exam at last question,This problem seem very interesting,and it's said can use the  knowledge of graph theory.But I don't understand this hint,can you someone can explain more detail ?

if you know chinese :you can see this post some idea and hint:[Interesting problem five](http://tieba.baidu.com/p/3411504099)

Comment: this links hint:We as a directed graph,$ 1,2,3,\cdots, n$ as a vertex from each point of $x$ to $f (x)$ connected to an edge, apparently this diagram consists of several disjoint rings with $k$ circle, since each fixed subset must complete contains a plurality of rings, so there are $2^k-1$ real subset (remove an empty set, then the conclusion is clearly established)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\cal S$ be the set of all fixed subsets, i.e. $A\in{\cal S}\iff f(A)=A$, and let $U=\bigcup{\cal S}$. Then it is easy to see that:

- $\emptyset\in {\cal S}$
- $A,B\in S\to A\cup B\in {\cal S}$
- $A\in S\to U\setminus A\in {\cal S}$

The second property implies that $U\in\cal S$, since it is a finite union, so $U$ is the largest subset of $I$ on which $f$ is bijective. Then the third property comes right out since $|f(U\setminus A)|=|U\setminus A|$.

Thus $\cal S$ is a finite boolean algebra, and so has $2^n$ elements for some $n$, i.e. it is an even number as long as $I\ne\emptyset$. Excluding the empty set gives $2^n-1$, which is odd. This $n$ can be explicitly constructed as the number of orbits in $f\upharpoonright U$.

Comment: No,This problem can't is bijective is also true

Comment: Yes,so your method is not true

Comment: fixed${}{}{}{}$

Comment: I think $f$ not must identity mapping,so I think you can't have $2^n-1$

Comment: What are you saying? I claim that for any function $f$, there is an $n$ with $|S\setminus\{\emptyset\}|=2^n-1$. For the identity map it is trivial since every subset is fixed, so you just take $n=|I|$.

Comment: I meaning is such $A=\{1,2,3,\cdots,k\},k<n$,then we can this Fixed subset numbers is $2^k-1$

Comment: @math110 I'm sorry, but your English is hampering my ability to understand what you want. Perhaps you could write more words, or use your native language (I can probably figure out any chinese, if that's your native language)?